# Citrix receiver screen resolution issue - fonts and icons too small

Tags: 18.04, display-resolution, citrix

I am using 18.04 and have configured Citrix receiver. The text and icon look very small when I am  into a remote using Citrix receiver.

For my work I need to log in to a remote machine using Citrix receiver.
The icons and other text all appears very small compared to what I see in my local machine. The screen resolution is 1920×1080.

How can I fix the resolution issue in the remote machine? When I use Windows I do not see any such problem.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely, you have a hidpi display. Like I do.

My yoga pro 2 has a 3200x1800 display. Even if I set the resolution to 1900x1080, when I connect using Citrix Receiver to my Work VM, it always sends 3200x1800 as the resolution.

Currently fixed it by adding fractional scaling to gnome.

KDE does not have this problem.

Another thing with Gnome, the <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> does not work to switch among the Remote Window's applications. In KDE, <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>  works as expected.

Look up the gsettings command to add fraction scaling. It is a beta feature right now. I do not know when Gnome will finally add fractional scaling to the official packages.